# Ebay Product API Empty Response

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, ebay-api

I am working on a project that requires access to eBay’s Product API. I am using the
`getProductDetails` call trying to get the fields containing eBay identification numbers (such as ePID, ISBN, GTIN, etc).

I tried two methods to get this call to produce the fields that I need, but I am only getting a "success" return but with no other details for the Python method and a 500 html response for the XML method. The two methods (XML and Python) I have tried so far are in working examples below. The keys I have obtained from Ebay are: appid, cevid, certid and token, which are saved in a .env file in the same directory as my code files.

I've spent days staring at the incomplete EBay API documentation, and EBay customer support pointed by to the [EBay SDK package](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python), which does not interface with the Product API.

Here's the Python GET request method:

```
root = 'https://svcs.ebay.com' 
endpoint = '/services/marketplacecatalog/ProductService/v1'  
headers = {'X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN': 'Bearer ' + OAuth, 
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
              'X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT':'JSON', 
              'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME': AppID} 
     
params = {'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME': 'getProductDetails', 
              'productDetailsRequest':'[0..*]',  
             'productDetailsRequest.productIdentifier.ePID':'EPID'+’115115562893’} #example ePID 
r = requests.get(root+endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
```

I expected output with the Product Details, especially GTIN and other identifiers, but instead I got:

```
{'getProductDetailsResponse': [{'ack': ['Success'], 
   'version': ['1.3.1'], 
   'timestamp': ['2021-12-02T17:34:18.510Z']}]}
```

With the XML POST method, the code is:

```
root = 'https://svcs.ebay.com' 
endpoint = '/services/marketplacecatalog/ProductService/v1' 
target_url = root + endpoint 
 
xml_request = """<?xml version="1.3.1" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<getProductDetailsRequest> 
  <productDetailsRequest>  
       <productIdentifier> 
         <ePID>EPID115115562893</ePID> #random ePID number  
      </productIdentifier> 
      <dataset>DisplayableProductDetails</dataset> 
  </productDetailsRequest> 
</getProductDetailsRequest>""" 
 
headers = {'X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN': 'Bearer ' + OAuth, 
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
           'Version': '1.3.1', 
          'X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT':'JSON', 
          'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME': AppID} 
 
r = requests.post(target_url, data=xml_request, headers=headers)
```

However this produces a 500 HTTP response.

I would be grateful for any help making a call that returns the eBay product identification numbers (ePID, ISBN, GTIN, etc). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear to me why you're using this API:
you wrote that you want to get the EPID(/ISBN/GTIN) number...
but in this call you have to supply the EPID therefore it is useless.

furthermore, AFAIK, this call is meant for EBAY-MOTOR only:
usually to get details of an item [getItem](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getitem.html) API is used

beside this, you cannot take some information from different pages, mix, and put values in a random way and expect it will work:
for example, you cannot put eBay API Version into xml declaration as you did in what you called `XML Version`:
`<?xml version="1.3.1" encoding="utf-8"?>`

You should read better the documentation, because if you just follow the instruction and the given example you can get a valid response:

```
https://svcs.ebay.com/services/marketplacecatalog/ProductService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=getProductDetails&SERVICE-VERSION=1.3.1&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-MOTOR&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&productDetailsRequest.productIdentifier.ePID=239142349&productDetailsRequest.dataset=DisplayableSearchResults&SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR_APP_ID`
```

you just have to add your `APP_ID` at the end